# How do I power down on reboot?

Tags: arch-linux, shutdown, reboot

I am programming for a Linux ARM device and have some situations where I need to reboot the device after a user prompt. Whenever I run `reboot -f` or `shutdown -r now` though, the system starts up with a kernel panic error.

If I manually reboot by unplugging the power it reboots perfectly fine.

Is there a way to power down on reboot? I feel like it might help me avoid a lot of grief.

Comment: `-h` for halt instead of `-r` for reboot.

Comment: `systemctl poweroff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reboot -p` instead. Do not force a reboot using `-f`.

Comment: Unfortunately it still results in the Kernel Panic

Comment: @TopGunCoder `reboot -p` *is* the way to power down on system halt. If you're getting a kernel panic, it means your kernel is buggy and you need to fix that.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate :P Thank you for the help :)

Comment: As it turns out my device was in a bad state, when I got it back into the production state (where the kernel panics would happen) the kernel panics wouldn't happen on reboot any more!